# is this methods enough for secure my host (php)?

Tags: php, security, xss

**i wanna make my host high Secure ( prevent attacks xss & CSRF ... )**

- first defense (token)

```php
if ( time() >= $_SESSION['token']['expire'] ) {
    $length = rand(31,50);
    try {
      $_SESSION['token']['code'] =  bin2hex(random_bytes($length));
      $_SESSION['token']['input'] =  bin2hex(random_bytes($length));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      $_SESSION['token']['code'] = substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, $length);
      $_SESSION['token']['input'] = substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, $length);
   }
   $_SESSION['token']['expire'] = time() + 3600;
   die(JSON_TIME_OUT);
}
```

- second defense (check all queries)

```php
$value = trim(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($POST['query']))));
```

- third defense (just allow post *REQUEST* )

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST' || sizeof($_GET)) {
    http_response_code(405);
    exit;
}
```

- forth defense ( for save password in db )

```php
$pass = password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

**Is there anything else I missed?**

Comment: Did you protect against SQL injection too? Anyway this is too broad, we don't know what else your application does, and therefore what else it might vulnerable too. Consult the OWASP list of top web application threats and consider whether you might have a vulnerability. If you're unsure, hire experienced security consultants to review your code and server environment.

Comment: Check out my answer.

Comment: If it was this easy, there would be no vulnerabilities.

Comment: `strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(...` you do realize you're first converting to ents `&lt;b&gt;` and then attempting to strip tags.

Comment: A default password makes no sense. It's like holding a massive sign outside your house "spare key under the flower pot".

Answer (score 1):

You missed SQL injection.

You can use prepared statements to avoid SQL injections.

Here is an example:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

$username = "someone";
$comments = "something like ); SELECT * FROM table;"; #some kind of sql injection
$current_date = date("h:i:s a d-m-Y");
        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (name, comments, date_publish) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            echo "An error occured!";
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $comment, $current_date);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            echo "Done!";
        }
```

Even though you have included *(php)* in your title, I want to share some security headers:

Add the following to Apache, if using Apache:

```
<IfModule headers_module>
Header always set Expires "-1"
Header always set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
Header always set Pragma "no-cache"

<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png|webp|ico|mp4|mp3)$">
Header always unset Expires
Header always set Cache-Control "must-revalidate, max-age=3600"
Header always unset Pragma
</FilesMatch>
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; img-src data: https: 'self'; script-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; style-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; form-action 'self'; media-src https: 'self'; frame-src 'none'; child-src 'none'; connect-src 'self'"
Header always set X-Frame-Options "DENY"
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" "expr=%{HTTPS} == 'on'"
#Header always set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer"
Header always set Permissions-Policy "geolocation=();midi=();notifications=();push=();sync-xhr=(self);microphone=();camera=();magnetometer=();gyroscope=();speaker=(self);vibrate=();fullscreen=(self);payment=();"
Header always set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
</IfModule>
```

Here are the plain headers:

```
set-cookie: __Secure-YOURSESSID=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
expires: -1
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
pragma: no-cache
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'; img-src data: https: 'self'; script-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; style-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; form-action 'self'; media-src https: 'self'; frame-src 'none'; child-src 'none'; connect-src 'self'
x-frame-options: DENY
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
permissions-policy: geolocation=();midi=();notifications=();push=();sync-xhr=(self);microphone=();camera=();magnetometer=();gyroscope=();speaker=(self);vibrate=();fullscreen=(self);payment=();
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

You can alter them to your needs. The `Content-Security-Policy` header is the most important one. It might break your site, but, it will help a lot.

Use [SSLLabs](https://ssllabs.com) to test your site's security.

Here is an Apache configuration for most secure [SSLLabs](https://ssllabs.com) score:

```
SSLCipherSuite TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd ECDHParameters secp384r1

#generate DH param using: openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 4096
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters "/path/to/ssl/dh4096.pem"

SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/usr/local/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
SSLUseStapling On
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:ssl_stapling(32768)"
```

Comment: i am not good in Apache, you mean put this code in .htaccess? **response headers** : ```HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 02 Feb 2021 20:43:26 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) PHP/7.4.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.9
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 1199
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json``` i think not working.right?

Comment: about SQL injections -> How does a hacker find the names of tables and columns?
Is it possible to run two queries in PDO?

Comment: Is it enough to use addcslashes?

Comment: @H.jalali, they can find your tables if they execute `SHOW TABLES`.